# How to show different activity one by one after on every time countdown timer of 30 seconds finish in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a timer of 30 seconds in my laucher activity and have three activity namely "A","B","C" in my app .what I want when timer gets finish after 30 seconds show Activity "A" and when user press a button in activity "A" he will be redirected to launcher activity and again timer of 30 seconds will start and when again timer finish he will be redirected to activity "B" and again when user press a button in activity "B" hew will be redirected to laucher activity and again timer of 30 seconds will start and same process user will follow for activity "C".How will I do that kindly guide.

Comment: Instead of timer use the Handler

Comment: I will recommend use the fragment instead of activity. Take single Activity & four fragments Splash, A, B, C it will be better to manage.

Comment: Kinldy give me code sample to lauch three activity one by one

Comment: If you want to go with activities then take one static variable in main activity as int and initialize it with 0 then, when you go on A activity and click on button set this int as 1 and from B set 2 and from C set 3 and check on main activity and redirect your next activity

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a timer in your launcher activity and use startActivityForResult to start A,B,C activity.

In your A,B,C activity button click, just set the resultCode and finish it.

Below is a simple example.

**Launcher Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handler;
    public static final int ACTIVITYA = 1;
    public static final int ACTIVITYB = 2;
    public static final int ACTIVITYC = 3;
    private int resultCode = ACTIVITYA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeActivity();
            }
        },3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        this.resultCode = resultCode;

    }

    private void changeActivity(){
        Intent intent;
        switch (resultCode){
            case ACTIVITYA :
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ActivityA.class);
                break;
            case  ACTIVITYB:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ActivityB.class);
                break;
            case ACTIVITYC:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ActivityC.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
}
```

**A,B,C Activity**

In button click function set resultCode to which activity you want to redirect and finish activity.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ActivityA.this.setResult(MainActivity.ACTIVITYB);
        finish();
        }
    });
```